# What happens when spring transaction isolation level conflicts with database transaction isolation level?

Tags: spring, database, spring-data

As I know database transaction isolation level is a prior, or spring can override it?
If database level has priority what are the cases to use spring isolation configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such separation as a "database transaction isolation level" and a "spring transaction isolation level".
A DB might implement the isolation levels defined by the SQL standard and a client that starts a transaction might request a specific level of isolation for it.

There are a couple of things to note that however do not present any contradiction:

- A DB usually has a default isolation level that is used if a client does not explicitly request a specific level for a transaction. Say, in PostgreSQL the default one is Read Committed and in MySQL it's Repeatable Read.
- A DB might not implement all of the isolation levels or have some specifics in their implementation. E.g. Oracle DB does not support the Read Uncommitted and Repeatable Read isolation levels and PostgreSQL's Read Uncommitted mode behaves like Read Committed.

With Spring, when you specify an isolation level either via the `@Transactional(isolation = ...)` annotation or `TransactionTemplate#setIsolationLevel()` it makes the JDBC driver issue an SQL command to set the desired level for the current session.

E.g. Oracle JDBC driver will do `ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL = READ COMMITTED` for Read Committed.
If an unsupported level is specified it'll throw an exception.

Refs:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm#CNCPT1312